# Is it enough check if $T(0) = 0$ in order to determine if a transformation is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

You need two conditions in order for a transformation to be linear:

- $T(a)+T(b)=T(a+b)$
- $T(c \cdot a)=c \cdot T(a)$

As I understand it this will, in turn, mean that:

- $T(0) = 0$

Now to my question. Is it enough to simply check if T(0) = 0? It seems to be the quickest way.

Comment: $T(x)=x^2$ is a quick counterexample.  You have to check the definition.

Answer (score 11):

Your reasoning is like this:

> You need two conditions in order for something to be a blue car: (1)
>   it must be blue, and (2) it must be a car.
>
> This, in turn, means that
>   it must be a car.
>
> So, to check whether something is a blue car, is it simply enough to check that it is a car?

Do you see what's wrong?

**Bonus**. You are right that *algorithmically*, rather than *deductively*, it may be best to start by checking whether $T(0)=0$.

If that is false, then $T$ is not linear. But if that is true, you do not have enough to conclude that $T$ is linear; you must do more work to tell.

The point is, $T(0)=0$ provides a quick way to *falsify* linearity, but it does not provide a quick way to *verify* linearity.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

No, being linear dos *not* mean that $T(0)=0$. It *implies* that $T(0)=0$, but it means much more than that. For instance, $\sin(0)=0$, but the sine function is not linear.